# PHP Limited foreach

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have an `array` that contain a lot of data from a `JSON` file using `json_decode`, and I want to loop over the data with a `foreach`.

**Example**

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json');
$data = json_decode(preg_replace('/(\])\](\R)\[/', '$1,$2', $json));
```

**Now I just do a foreach to get the data one by one**

```
foreach($data as $d){
  ...
}
```

But the foreach seems limited, it doesn't give me all the data of the file but only some of these and I don't understand why, any idea why and how to solve this ?

**Original string: (invalid JSON)** https://paste.ee/r/RN7rK

**Modified structure and `json_decode` result** `(using print_r)` : I can't post it, it's too large so try my `preg_replace` and then `print_r`

Comment: please provide the decoded json data..and tell which data you need to get from it..!!

Comment: Also, you're modifiying the JSON structure before you parse it, from something that seems to be illegal syntax - could you add some relevant content of the `data.json`?

Comment: Could you give an example a data item in the original file which you are not getting?

Comment: Could you `echo count($data)` before the loop and tell what you get?

Comment: I've got 7516 when I count

Comment: That counts all of them. I do notice -- and this may be the problem -- that in the last 500 entries, the number of elements in the array is 19 instead of 22 like in the first 6000 entries. But it is like that in the source data. It seems to depend on the value of the first array element. When it is *"s"* you're looking at a 22-array, when it is "*i*" it is a 19-array.

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, I suggest you show some of the code you have within the foreach loop, and we'll take it from there.

Comment: For me the correct total number of items is 7516. How do you have checked missing items?

Comment: You really need to clarify what **exactly** made you claim *it doesn't give me all the data of the file*. What is missing? Are you sure? Example?

Comment: Missings items are approximatively 7000 entries

Comment: 7000 out of 7516 or 7000 out of 14516?

Comment: Please add a counter variable to test this. First set it to zero `$counter = 0;` then inside of your foreach loop incrment it (`$counter++`) and display its value  after the loop: `echo $counter;`. What is the result?

Comment: That regex is not needed - there's 75 lines of correct json data, each containing 100 entries except for the last, containing 16. Alternative: `$all = [];
foreach ( explode( "\n", file_get_contents('data.json') ) as $line )
  $all = array_merge( $all, json_decode($line) );`. You can use the first entry to detect the record type: `foreach ( $all as $foo ) { if ( $foo[0] == 's' ) { /* count($foo): 22 */ } elseif ( $foo[0] == 'i' ) { /* count($foo): 19 */ } }`.

Comment: The fact that we run the script with PHP CLI may cause that problem ?

Comment: @MrZ, I am still waiting for the answer to my question of 2 hours ago. It is not clear to me whether you say that your foreach loop does not iterative enough times (7516) or whether you have another issue inside that loop that makes you miss records. Please provide the output of the counter I suggested and explain what exactly is not working in more detail.

Comment: Sorry, I've forget to answer you. I got this 7516

Comment: I make a foreach to download some images that I get the id with the foreach

Comment: @MrZ, if you count 7516 rows and the loop iterates 7516 times and the data has 7516 entries, why are you saying *"it doesn't give me all the data of the file."*. You **really need to clarify that statement**!! See my comment of 18 hours ago. What are you missing!?

Comment: I'm making some tests to see why, I think it came from the errors that I get (but these errors aren't important beacause the script continue)

Answer (score 1):

There are 7516 records in your JSON decoded array.

This record set has two different sections:

- The first section of 6970 records has records with 22 elements, and the first one has value *"s"*. First occurrence is this:

  ```
  ["s","13","shelves_norja","49500","0","1","1","#ffffff,#F7EBBC",
   "Beige Bookcase", "For nic naks and books.","","5", "true", "-1",
   "false","","1","true","0","0","0","false"]
  ```
- The second section of 546 has records with 19 elements, and the first one has value *"i"*. First occurrence:

  ```
  ["i","1", "post.it",      "0",    "", "", "", "",
   "Pad of stickies","Pad of stickies",        "","-1","false","-1",
   "false","","5","false",           "false"]
  ```

I added white space before that last record's last element, to highlight the difference:

The first type has 3 numerical fields before the last field which are lacking in the second type of record.

So in your code, you'll need to test the number of array elements, and give default values for those three elements.

You could achieve this with this code:

```
foreach ($data as $d){
    if (count($d) == 19) {
        array_splice($d, 18, 0, array("0", "0", "0"));
    }
    // rest of your code
}
```

This will inject the three *"missing"* elements into arrays of 19 elements so they get the same structure as the others.

**Alternatively,** you could do the opposite, and delete the three elements from the longer array values, but be aware that these elements are not always containing zeroes, so you would then effectively lose information.

Still, as you have said in comments you are lacking about 7000 records, this suggests that you have a problem in processing the longer arrays. If you want to go for this alternative your code becomes:

```
foreach ($data as $d){
    if (count($d) == 22) {
        array_splice($d, 18, 3);
    }
    // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Performing this test the records are 7516:

```
/* My original json manipulation:  */                                       # 01
if( 1 )
{
    $json = preg_replace('/[\n\r\t]/','',$json);
    $json = str_replace( '][', '],[', $json );
    $json = preg_replace( '/\[\[+/', '[', $json );
    $json = preg_replace( '/\]\]+/', ']', $json );
    $json = "[$json]";
}
/* Your original json manipulation:  */
else
{
    $json = preg_replace('/(\])\](\R)\[/', '$1,$2', $json);
}

$data = json_decode( $json );                                               # 02

/* Inverse test:  */
$lost = 0;
foreach( $data as $row )
{
    $enc = json_encode( $row );
    if( FALSE===strpos( $json, $enc ) ) $lost++;                            # 03
    else $json = str_replace( $enc, '', $json );
}
$json  = preg_replace('/],,+\[/','],[',$json);                              # 04
$found = explode( '],[',$json );

echo "Total: ".count($data).PHP_EOL;
echo "Lost:  $lost".PHP_EOL;
echo "Found: ".count($found).PHP_EOL;
```

At step **#01** you can find my json manipulation. It can be shortened, but I leave it for clarity. You can change `if( 1 )` to `if( 0 )` to apply your regex.

After json decoding (**#02**), I perform an inverse test: I process each decoded array value re-encoding it in json and searching if they exists in the json string (**#03**): if they exists, I delete it from the json string, otherwise I increment the `$lost` variable.

After the `foreach` loop, I reduce multiple occurrences of `,` in the transformed json string, then I split it by `],[` in array.

At the end, I print the total number of items in decoded json, the total lost items and the total rows of modified json.
Using my manipulation, the result is ‘Lost:65, Found:65’, using your manipulation the result is ‘Lost:65, Found:45’ (but I don't have re-edited final json transformation for this).

Given that the number of Lost/Found is the same, I think that there is a good chance that no elements remains undecoded, but if you want you can perform a more accurate check declaring `$lost`as array and then, at **#03**, changing the line in this way:

```
if( FALSE===strpos( $json, $enc ) ) $lost[] = $enc;
```

Then, at end of `foreach` loop:

```
(...)
$found = explode( '],[',$json );
print_r( $lost );
print_r( $found );
```

and then check it manually if each not found item has a corresponding value in the remaining modified json.

PS: They are ‘lost’ records due to encoding special characters issue.

Comment: Interesting ideas! I do think it is a bit risky to do replacements of square brackets without also testing the new line characters, as these sequences can in theory occur within strings. For instance, the data contains somewhere "[pixel]". This will not pose a problem for your code, but imagine a value of "[pixel][other pixel]" appearing in the data...

Comment: @trincot Yes, you are totally right. For this the first two lines of my replacement can be condensed in `preg_replace('/\][\n\r\t]\[/','],[',$json)`. BTW My primary intent was to check data-loss. My replacing steps are progressive performed to obtains a valid json at jsonlint.